# Java collections synchronization

Tags: java, collections, synchronization

I want to ask for advice with synchronization of Map in Java.

```
public class EventManager{

    protected final Map<Class<?>, Object> eventList;

    public void register(Class<?> key, Object object){
        eventList.put(key, object);
    }

    public void read(){
       for(Class<?> key : eventList.keySet()){
           // Next stuff
       }
    }
}
```

I think that both methods should be synchronized with Map as monitor, like:

```
public class EventManager{

    protected final Map<Class<?>, Object> eventList;

    public void register(Class<?> key, Object object){
        synchronized(eventList){
            eventList.put(key, object);
        }
    }

    public void read(){
       synchronized(eventList){
           for(Class<?> key : eventList.keySet()){
               // Next stuff
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Or is there some other way how to solve it, like:

```
eventList = Collections.synchronizedMap(...);    
eventList = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

I need to know answer to question, that even if I use **Collections.synchronizedMap** or **ConcurrentHashMap**, I will need to synchronized both methods with map object.

Thank you, for your advice.

Comment: It depends: do you want to prevent chang to the map while iterating in the read method?

Comment: Generally yes, but I can use for it java.util.Iterator. But It depends on, if it cause problem with Java Runtime. Iterating through the map, while is beeing changed.

Comment: This question is answered in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html